# No values in $_POST after submitting the form

Tags: php

I have just started coding in PHP and I am having some issues to make this code work. I have tried to change from `$_POST` to `$HTTP_POST_VARS` , but I still cant get the value, anybody could point me what am I doing wrong and how to fix this code?

```
<?php


$email_address = "email@email.com";
// your e-mail address goes here

$email_subject = "Online Enquiry";
// the subject line for the e-mail goes here

$from_email_name = "email@email.com";
// the from address goes here 

$redirect_to_page = "thankyou.html";
// enter the web address where the user should be sent after completing the form

//*********************************
// DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE!!!**
//*********************************


$mailTo = "$email_address";

$mailSubject = "$email_subject";

$mailBody = "The form values entered by the user are as follows: \n\n";

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{

 $mailBody .= "$key = $value\n";

}



$mailBody .= "\n\n";


 $fromHeader = "From: $from_email_name\n";


if(mail($mailTo, $mailSubject, $mailBody, $fromHeader)) 
{

    print ("<B><br></b>");

}

echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV=\"REFRESH\" content=\"0; url=$redirect_to_page\">";

?>
```

My HTML form.

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
<input type="text" class="textbox" value=" Your Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your Name';}">
<input type="text" class="textbox" value="Your E-Mail" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your E-Mail';}">
<div class="clear"> </div>
<div>
<textarea value="Message:" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your Message ';}">Your Message</textarea>
</div>                          
<div class="submit"> 
<input type="submit" value="SEND " />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: "and im new in this PHP thing" Run while you're in time son

Comment: after form submit try printing `$_POST);`.

Comment: you're not using anything in $_POST. you're just testing is $_POST is not empty. `$key` and `$value` are also undefined. you need a `foreach($_POST as $key => $value)`, most likely.

Comment: @ArturPeniche Don't scare off the newbies like that. PHP is a wonderful kick starter into the programming world.

Comment: @MarcB I have tested as well.. still not working.

Comment: `not working` **HOW**? do you get your `<b><br></b>` output? If not, then `mail()` is failing.

Comment: You have `method="post"` in your form???

Comment: @MarcB after I press Submit, I get the email.. but the Content is like this. The form values entered by the user are as follows: without any value.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes i did.

Comment: leave the guesswork out, and post your HTML form

Comment: I'm betting on no name attributes (or typos) and possibly no form POST method. Error reporting will tell you that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have posted the HTML form.

Comment: I was right; no name attributes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks!! it is working now =) after adding name attributes

Comment: You're welcome Marcus, I closed the question since it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Answer (score -1):

See var_dump($_REQUEST). Default form submit uses $_GET object.